# HDF error while writing new netCDF file using netCDF4 module

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

Right now, I'm working with a WRF output and trying to extract the `T` variable of all of my output files into a new `nc` file. In order to do this, I'm using the following code:

```py
import wrf
import numpy as np
import os
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import xarray as xr
WRF_DIRECTORY = "/home/r.guzman/disco3/sensibilidad/sensit01/Descargados"
WRF_FILES = ["wrfout_d01_2022-03-13_00:00:00",
             "wrfout_d01_2022-03-15_02:00:00",
             "wrfout_d01_2022-03-17_04:00:00",
             "wrfout_d01_2022-03-19_06:00:00"]

_WRF_FILES = [os.path.abspath(os.path.expanduser(
    os.path.join(WRF_DIRECTORY, f))) for f in WRF_FILES]

def single_wrf_file():
    global _WRF_FILES
    return _WRF_FILES[0]

def multiple_wrf_files():
    global _WRF_FILES
    return _WRF_FILES

file_paths = multiple_wrf_files()

wrf_files = [Dataset(f) for f in file_paths]

ds = wrf.combine_files(wrf_files, 'T', timeidx=wrf.ALL_TIMES, is_moving = True)

del ds.attrs['projection']

ds.to_netcdf("sensit01_T.nc")
```

After some execution time, I finally get the following error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1073, in to_netcdf
    dataset, store, writer, encoding=encoding, unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1119, in dump_to_store
    store.store(variables, attrs, check_encoding, writer, unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims)
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 266, in store
    variables, check_encoding_set, writer, unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 307, in set_variables
    writer.add(source, target)
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py", line 156, in add
    target[...] = source
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 69, in __setitem__
    data[key] = value
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 5487, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__setitem__
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 5770, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._put
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2014, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py", line 2844, in to_netcdf
    return dataset.to_netcdf(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py", line 1912, in to_netcdf
    invalid_netcdf=invalid_netcdf,
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1088, in to_netcdf
    store.close()
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/netCDF4_.py", line 510, in close
    self._manager.close(**kwargs)
  File "/home/r.guzman/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xarray/backends/file_manager.py", line 222, in close
    file.close()
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2607, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.close
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2570, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset._close
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2014, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
```

I already tried reinstalling the python modules and with another set of files, so I was wondering what I could do to solve this. Any insights would be useful.

Comment: Using the netCDF4 module to load data sets is outdated. Try using `xarray` to open the data sets: `ds = xr.open_dataset("path/to/your/dataset.nc")`.